# Не пойму, что делает функция bind() в коде

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Здравствуйте, недавно начал изучать Boost.Asio, и в одном из примеров не могу понять, что делает функция bind() в коде данной программы.
Если кто знает, для чего придназначена эта функция, пожалуйста, объясните. Так как я недавно начал углубляться в библиотеку STL и Boost. Заранее спасибо.

```
io_service service;
size_t read_complete(char * buff, const error_code & err, size_t bytes) 
{
    if ( err) return 0;
    bool found = std::find(buff, buff + bytes, '\n') < buff + bytes;
    // we read one-by-one until we get to enter, no buffering
    return found ? 0 : 1;
}
```

void handle_connections() 
{
    ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(service, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(),8001));
    char buff[1024];
    while ( true) 
    {
        ip::tcp::socket sock(service);
        acceptor.accept(sock);
        int bytes = read(sock, buffer(buff), boost::bind(read_complete,buff,_1,_2));
        std::string msg(buff, bytes);
        sock.write_some(buffer(msg));
        sock.close();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    handle_connections();
}

Comment: На конец то я понял для чего эта функция. А то как бы я читал докуминтацию и ничего не мог розобрать. Спасибо)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`std:bind` (я буду говорить об `std::bind`, так как эта функция перенесена в стандарт C++ из boost) - это адаптер функциональных объектов, который позволяет адаптировать функциональные объекты под заданное число параметров.

Чтобы было более ясно ее назначение, допустим вы решили написать функцию вывода произвольного целочисленного массива в поток `std::cout` . Ваша программа могла бы выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>

void display( const int a[], size_t n )
{    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {        
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }       
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    display( a, N );
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Но затем вам пришла в голову идея усовершенствовать функцию вывода таким образом, чтобы она не просто выводила элементы массива, как они есть, но и делала какие-то с ними преобразования перед выводом.

Поэтому вы решили добавить параметр в функцию, который будет представлять некоторую операцию над элементами массива. Этот третий параметр вы объявили как функцию с одним параметром. Используя эту функцию, вы можете, например, вывести на консоль удвоенные значения элементов массива с помощью лямбда-выражения:

```
#include <iostream>

void display( const int a[], size_t n, int operation( int ) )
{    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {        
        std::cout << operation( a[i] ) << ' ';
    }       
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    auto doubled = []( int x ) { return 2 * x; };
    display( a, N, doubled );
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

В данном случае возможно использовать лямбда-выражение `doubled`, потому что оно может быть неявно преобразовано в функцию с одним параметром, так как не имеет замыкания.

Но, допустим, вы решили выводить на печать не только удвоенные значения элементов массива, но и значения элементов, умноженных на некоторый коэффициент, который задается во время выполнения программы.

В этом случае ваша программа могла бы выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>

void display( const int a[], size_t n, int operation( int ) )
{    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {        
        std::cout << operation( a[i] ) << ' ';
    }       
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    int  factor = 2;

    auto multiplies = [&factor]( int x ) { return factor * x; };

    display( a, N, multiplies );

    factor = 3;

    display( a, N, multiplies );
}
```

Однако она не будет компилироваться. Проблема заключается в том, что если лямбда-выражение содержит замыкание,

```
auto multiplies = [&factor]( int x ) { return factor * x; };
                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

то оно не имеет неявного преобразования в указатель на функцию.

Поэтому придется написать шаблонную функцию, которая будет иметь шаблонный параметр операции и в качестве аргумента может принимать не только функции, но и объекты классов, который имеют оператор вызова функции `operator ()`. 
Ваша программа будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class Operation>
void display( const int a[], size_t n, Operation operation )
{    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {        
        std::cout << operation( a[i] ) << ' ';
    }       
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    int  factor = 2;

    auto multiplies = [&factor]( int x ) { return factor * x; };

    display( a, N, multiplies );

    factor = 3;

    display( a, N, multiplies );
}
```

Вывод на консоль соответственно будет:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
```

Но теперь, допустим, вы решили вывести на печать квадраты значений элементов массива. Вы опять бы могли использовать лямбда-выражение, как, например,

```
auto_square = []( int x ){ return x * x; };
```

И ваша программа успешно бы выполнилась, используя это лямбда-выражение.

Но вы знаете, что стандарт уже имеет функциональный объект `std::multiplies`, который осуществляет операцию `x * y` для двух аргументов своего оператора вызова функции `operator ()`.

Как им воспользоваться? Оператор этого функционального объекта принимает два аргумента, тогда как в нашей функции `display` функциональный объект принимает только один аргумент.

Для этого используются функциональные адаптеры и, в частности, `std::bind`. Он может "превратить" функциональный объект `std::multiplies` из объекта, который принимает два аргумента в объект, который принимает один аргумент.

Программа будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <class Operation>
void display( const int a[], size_t n, Operation operation )
{    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {        
        std::cout << operation( a[i] ) << ' ';
    }       
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    auto square = bind( std::multiplies<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_1 );

    display( a, N, square );
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет

```
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100
```

Внутри функции `display` объект `square` вызывается как `square( a[i] )`,
который в свою очередь делегирует работу объекту класса `std::multiplies<int>`,
вызывая его как

```
std::multiplies<int>()( a[i], a[i] );
```

Конечно конструктор `std::multiplies<int>` не вызывается, так как объект данного класса уже был создан, когда создавался объект `square`

```
auto square = bind( std::multiplies<int>(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_1 );
```

Вызывался только `operator ()` этого объекта.

В вашем примере вызов `read` требует в качестве третьего аргумента функциональный объект, который принимает только два аргумента:

```
int bytes = read(sock, buffer(buff), boost::bind(read_complete,buff,_1,_2));
```

Однако, вы хотите, чтобы вызывалась функция `read_complete`, которая принимает три аргумента вместо двух. В этом случае используется адаптер `bind`, который сам получает два аргумента, как того требует вызов функции `read`, но делегирует работу функции `read_complete`, передавая ей три аргумента: два своих, обозначенных как `_1` и `_2`, и которые ей передает внутри своего тела функция `read`, когда ее вызывает, и один дополнительный, `buff`, который она сохранила внутри себя, когда использовалась в качестве аргумента вызова `read`.

Answer (score 13):

[bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html) это немного интересная функция (не путать с функцией работы сокетами, которая также называется [bind](http://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=bind&category=2)!!!). Ее задача создать одну функцию на базе другой, подставив часть аргументов (это называется "[частичным применением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)").

Посмотрим глубже. Функция [read](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload7.html) требует трех параметров - сокета, буфера для данных и "функции завершения" (вообще то у этой бустовой read всего восемь различных перегруженных вариантов). Эта функция будет вызываться, что бы определить, что данных прочитано достаточно. Там же в справке приведена сигнатура этой функции. У нее два параметра: код ошибки последнего чтения и сколько байт прочитано. Но что делать, если нет подходящей функции?

Для этого есть bind. Он первым аргументом принимает функцию (в данном случае `read_complete`, а дальше аргументы. Так как исходная функция `read_complete` имела три аргумента, а функции read нужно только два, то один аргумент подставляется явно (первый), а вместо двух других - заглушки специального вида.

В результате, когда функции read нужно будет вызвать функцию завершения, она вызовет `read_complete`, первый аргумент ей подставит bind, а два вторых будут подставлены с аргументов.

```
Если попробовать написать код схематически, то все выглядит где то так

io_service service;
size_t read_complete(char * buff, const error_code & err, size_t bytes) 
{
    if ( err) return 0;
    bool found = std::find(buff, buff + bytes, '\n') < buff + bytes;
    // we read one-by-one until we get to enter, no buffering
    return found ? 0 : 1;
}

char buff[1024];
size_t new_func(const error_code & err, size_t bytes) 
{
  return read_complete(buff, err, bytes);
}

void handle_connections() 
{
    ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(service, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(),8001));

    while ( true) 
    {
        ip::tcp::socket sock(service);
        acceptor.accept(sock);
        int bytes = read(sock, buffer(buff), new_func);
        std::string msg(buff, bytes);
        sock.write_some(buffer(msg));
        sock.close();
    }
}
```

Как видите, мне пришлось сделать буфер глобальным, что бы новоиспеченная функция имела к нему доступ. На самом деле переменная глобальной не становится, но это был самый простой способ эмулировать поведение.

Эта функция bind пришла в с++ с функциональных языков вида haskell и лисп, где подобное встречается на каждом шагу.