# Способы передачи функции(функтора) в качестве аргумента другой функции

Tags: c++, c++11

Наткнулся тут на [вопрос про `std::bind`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/446124/177333) и возник вопрос.

Чем отличается способ с шаблоном

```
template <class Operation>
void display( int a[], size_t n, Operation op ) // или Operation&&
{    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {        
        std::cout << op( a[i] ) << ' ';
    }       
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

от

```
void display( int a[], size_t n, std::function<int( int )> operation )
{    
    //...
}
```

и от

```
void display( int a[], size_t n, int operation( int ) )
{    

}
```

Какие возможности и ограничения у того или иного способа, когда их нужно применять.

Comment: [Should I use std::function or a function pointer in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848690/should-i-use-stdfunction-or-a-function-pointer-in-c)

Comment: А очень хороший вопрос, кстати.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вариант принимает любой объект, не проверяя его тип. Так, если туда передать что-то, что не может быть вызвано, или что-то, что возвращает тип, который не может быть использован в `cout`, то получите не совсем релевантную ошибку компиляции.

Второй вариант принимает любой объект, который может быть вызван. При это согласованность сигнатур проверяется сразу и выдаётся релевантная ошибка, что позволяет быстрее понять, где проблема.

Третий вариант принимает лишь свободные функции и лямбды без состояний и является более ограниченным чем второй вариант. Использовать третий вариант в современном C++ коде нет никакого смысла.

Касательно применения: стоит всегда использовать `std::function`, за исключением тех моментов, когда это по каким-то причинам вредит.

Answer (score 3):

Первый способ передает функтор в метод статически - что позволяет компилятору заинлайнить его вызов, если функтор достаточно короткий.

Второй способ позволяет избавиться от шаблонов - но ценой вызова виртуального метода; такой метод уже не получится заинлайнить в общем случае (тем не менее, компилятор все еще может заинлайнить его если перед этим заинлайнил `display`).

Третий способ позволяет передать только функцию, но не функтор.

Comment: А в каком Си++ разрешили приведение лямбд, не использующих захват переменных, к указателям на функции? Или это было только предложение?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Насколько мне помнится, таки-да, разрешили.

Comment: @VladD, а с какой версии? 14 или новее?

Comment: По мнению gcc, с 11-ой: http://pastebin.com/U5NdYLMF

Comment: @Qwertiy, эта возможность есть с появления лямд, т.е. с C++11

Answer (score 2):

Если переданная функция вызывается в цикле, то предпочтительнее передавать ее как шаблонный параметр, чтобы компилятор мог ее заинлайнить. Обычно функторы - это небольшие объекты, и их можно передавать по значению.

Если возможности для инлайна нет (например переданная функция кладется в `list<function<y(x)>>`), то можно сразу использовать параметр с типом `function<y(x)>`.

Указатель на функцию следует использовать только если всегда будет передаваться и храниться именно указатель на функцию. `std::function<>` имеет размер около 4 указателей (зависит от реализации), и иногда хочется избежать x4 расходов на хранение и копирование, если известно что надо хранить только указатели на функции.